# Is it possible to have a fb bot send out a link every time something is posted?

Tags: facebook, heroku, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

So the question is in the title. Basically, at the moment I have finished making the tutorial FB Messenger bot. I used Heroku to get the URL and everything running.

My issue currently is that I can't find anyway as how to make the bot send messages out to the people who have liked its page without a received message.

The end goal is to get the bot to send out a link updating its followers on any new posts made.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: that would be spam. you can´t just send messages to people just because they liked your page. luckily, that´s not possible.

Comment: Ya, I thought so, ok how about instead an automated message. Like the one that TechCrunches bot does. But doesn't that do the same? Sends a message to all of its users.

Comment: what do you mean? all users of what? you can send messages to bot users, but you cannot send messages to page fans.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my wording is off but what I meant was the bot users. I understand that I can send them messages. But so far only when they write in a keyword otherwise my bot goes to its default message. I wanted to make it so that everyone that is using my bot at a certain time of day would get something like an automated message. I've seen other bots do it so I assume it's not seen as spam. I just wanted to know the process of going about doing that.

Comment: afaik there is no broadcast, so you have to store all scoped user ids in your own database and send each user a message - with a batch request, for example. check out the docs about those.

Comment: Thanks, luschn will do.